# Decode data using openssl that has been encoded using java

Tags: java, c++, openssl

I have to interface with a system written in java that encrypts data using the following java method:

```
public final void rsaEncrypt(String data, String filePath) {
    try {
            Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            PublicKey pubKey = readKeyFromFile("/" + Constants.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_NAME, filePath);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Constants.RSA_INSTANCE);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            writeToFile(Constants.ENCRYPTED_STRING_FILE_NAME, filePath, encoder.encodeToString(cipherData));
        } catch (BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            if (LOG.isErrorEnabled())
                LOG.error("Error encrypting String.", e);
            throw new EncryptionException("Error encrypting data", e);
        }
}
```

My code is written in c++ using openssl:

```
std::string prv =
    "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
     // cut  key data

    "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";  
BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)prv.c_str(), -1);
RSA* rsaPrivKey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (!rsaPrivKey)
    printf("ERROR: Could not load PRIVATE KEY!  PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey FAILED: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

BIO_free(bio);
// where enc[] holds the Base64 decoded data, but len becomes -1  and no data is decoded.
int len = RSA_private_decrypt(64,(unsigned char *)&enc, (unsigned char *)&dec, private_key_, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

I can decode data I encrypt myself with the public key, but don't seem to match the java options for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried calling `ERR_get_error` to get more details on the error state?

Comment: I resolved this as it turned out that the Java code didn't create their keys properly and didn't reflect the .pem files that was given to me.

Answer (score 0):

These is no answer here as like my comment said, it turns out the Java code was incorrect in creating their keys, which were not matching the .pem files I was given.